# How do I enumerate web folders in C# that are not mapped to network drives (like "net use")

Tags: c#, sharepoint, webdav, net-use, web-folders

From the command line, one can call [net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) without any parameters and obtain a list of computer connections on the local computer. This provides a listing of mapped network drives, as well as network connections to local network shares and web folders that were defined using the `net use` command.

One can create a network connection to a local network share as follows:

```
net use \\MyComputerName\MyShareName
```

One can create a network connection to a web folder (e.g. WebDAV or SharePoint) as follows:

```
net use http://MySharePoint:12345/Shared%20Documents/MyFolder
```

Calling `net use` will list the connections as follows:

```
C:\>net use
New connections will be remembered.


Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unavailable  Q:        \\OldServer\OldShare      Microsoft Windows Network
OK           U:        \\MyServerName\Name of Shared Folder
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
Unavailable  W:        http://MyOldSharePoint   Web Client Network
             X:        \\MyWebDavServer@12345\DavWWWRoot
                                                Web Client Network
                       \\MySharePoint@12345\Shared%20Documents\MyFolder
                                                Web Client Network
OK                     \\MyComputerName\MyShareName
                                                Microsoft Windows Network
OK                     \\HostName\ShareName      Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

**Mapped Network Drives**

I am able to obtain the mapped drives in C# by calling `DriveInfo.GetDrives()`.

**Net Use Connections to Network Shares**

I am able to obtain the connections to network shares that I created through PInvoke and the use of the Windows API `NetUseEnum`.

**Net Use Connections to Web Folders**

I was able to obtain a listing of the Web Client Network servers through the use of the Windows APIs `WNetOpenEnum` and `WNetEnumResource`, however this does not get me the full path through to the share name and folders; it only gets me the server name.

I have not been able to find a way to obtain the Web Client Network connections to web folders that `net use` allows you to define.

I am sure there must be a Windows API that can return these. If anyone knows, please advise. I certainly would like to avoid having to use a poor man's solution, such as calling `net use` via a command line process and parse its output.

**Note:** I do not want a solution that uses WMI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure the Win32_LogicalDisk class should contain the info you need, if not try the registry, examples for both methods are in the Get-or-List-Network-shares-in-CSharp-using-WMI article

links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/02/Get-or-List-Network-shares-in-CSharp-using-WMI.html

Comment: Registry is non-optimum. I would be interested an a Win32 API. Surely, I would expect that "net use" is calling some Windows API.

Comment: Theres a solution in the link that uses DirectoryEntry it uses ActiveDs com object

Comment: I tried the sample code using the DirectoryEntry and it does not provide what I need. It returns for "localhost" all locally defined folder shares. That is not what I need. I can get these from the Windows API NetShareEnum. What I am looking for are the specific network connections to remote web folders per the examples I showed on the Web Client Network (configured through "net use").

Comment: Think you may have what you need here also seems a dup on so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918477/how-can-i-enumerate-network-shares-and-web-folders-in-c http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2939/Network-Shares-and-UNC-paths

Comment: The duplicate you mention is a post I made 2 years ago. It is not exactly the same. At the time I was looking to browse through all types of folders and shares that were mapped network drives or configured as network locations. I have since resolved those requirements. The response given was a solution to enumerate local folder shares or WMI. Again, this particular question at hand is very specifically about **network connections to remote web folders established through "net use"**, not local folder shares, not Mapped Network Drives and not "Windows Network Locations".