# GetLogicalDrives for \\tsclient\

Tags: c#, directory, remote-desktop

I am currently working on a custom explorer and would like to allow the user to use the explorer on a remote computer, but still access the drives on their own computer.

Now, I have already read a lot of information on this subject and apparently I need to use `WNetOpenEnum` and `WNetEnumResource` to get an enumeration of network resources (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918477/how-can-i-enumerate-network-shares-and-web-folders-in-c)). Unfortunately, I have not yet been successful in doing so.

So I was wondering if there is an easier way to access the paths of the drives.
One possibility would be to simply check all common names for their existence (\\tsclient\C , \\tsclient\D etc.). Not a very good one, though.

So before I get any further into making `WNetEnumResource` work, I thought I'd check to see if I've overlooked something that makes it easy to return all tsclient paths. Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found [a working solution](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr.wnetenumresource):

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WNETOE(null);
    }


    // Coded by Eugene E. Zhukovsky, 8.21.2002
    // Added by Kill
    // declare the DLL import functions

    [DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int WNetEnumResource(
        IntPtr hEnum,
        ref int lpcCount,
        IntPtr lpBuffer,
        ref int lpBufferSize);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int WNetOpenEnum(
        RESOURCE_SCOPE dwScope,
        RESOURCE_TYPE dwType,
        RESOURCE_USAGE dwUsage,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)][In] Object lpNetResource,
        out IntPtr lphEnum);

    [DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int WNetCloseEnum(IntPtr hEnum);
    //declare the structures to hold info

    public enum RESOURCE_SCOPE
    {
        RESOURCE_CONNECTED = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCE_GLOBALNET = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCE_REMEMBERED = 0x00000003,
        RESOURCE_RECENT = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCE_CONTEXT = 0x00000005
    }

    public enum RESOURCE_TYPE
    {
        RESOURCETYPE_ANY = 0x00000000,
        RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCETYPE_PRINT = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCETYPE_RESERVED = 0x00000008,
    }

    public enum RESOURCE_USAGE
    {
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_NOLOCALDEVICE = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_SIBLING = 0x00000008,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED = 0x00000010,
        RESOURCEUSAGE_ALL = (RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE | RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER | RESOURCEUSAGE_ATTACHED),
    }

    public enum RESOURCE_DISPLAYTYPE
    {
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GENERIC = 0x00000000,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DOMAIN = 0x00000001,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SERVER = 0x00000002,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE = 0x00000003,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_FILE = 0x00000004,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_GROUP = 0x00000005,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NETWORK = 0x00000006,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_ROOT = 0x00000007,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHAREADMIN = 0x00000008,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_DIRECTORY = 0x00000009,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_TREE = 0x0000000A,
        RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_NDSCONTAINER = 0x0000000B
    }

    public struct NETRESOURCE
    {
        public RESOURCE_SCOPE dwScope;
        public RESOURCE_TYPE dwType;
        public RESOURCE_DISPLAYTYPE dwDisplayType;
        public RESOURCE_USAGE dwUsage;
        [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string lpLocalName;
        [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string lpRemoteName;
        [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string lpComment;
        [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public string lpProvider;
    }

    //the function we'll be calling
    public static void WNETOE(Object o)
    {
        int iRet;
        IntPtr ptrHandle = new IntPtr();
        try
        {
            iRet = WNetOpenEnum(
            RESOURCE_SCOPE.RESOURCE_GLOBALNET,
            RESOURCE_TYPE.RESOURCETYPE_ANY,
            RESOURCE_USAGE.RESOURCEUSAGE_ALL,
            o,
            out ptrHandle);
            if (iRet != 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            int entries;
            int buffer = 16384;
            IntPtr ptrBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffer);
            NETRESOURCE nr;
            for (; ; )
            {
                entries = -1;
                buffer = 16384;
                iRet = WNetEnumResource(ptrHandle, ref entries, ptrBuffer, ref buffer);
                if ((iRet != 0) || (entries < 1))
                {
                    break;
                }
                IntPtr ptr = ptrBuffer;
                for (int i = 0; i < entries; i++)
                {
                    nr = (NETRESOURCE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(NETRESOURCE));
                    if (RESOURCE_USAGE.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER == (nr.dwUsage
                        & RESOURCE_USAGE.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONTAINER))
                    {
                        //call recursively to get all entries in a container
                        WNETOE(nr);
                    }
                    ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(nr);
                    Console.WriteLine(" {0} : LocalName='{1}' RemoteName='{2}'",
                    nr.dwDisplayType.ToString(), nr.lpLocalName, nr.lpRemoteName);
                }
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrBuffer);
            iRet = WNetCloseEnum(ptrHandle);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }



    //here's some possible error codes
    public enum NERR
    {
        NERR_Success = 0,/* Success */
        ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234, // dderror
        ERROR_NO_BROWSER_SERVERS_FOUND = 6118,
        ERROR_INVALID_LEVEL = 124,
        ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5,
        ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
        ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 8,
        ERROR_NETWORK_BUSY = 54,
        ERROR_BAD_NETPATH = 53,
        ERROR_NO_NETWORK = 1222,
        ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE_STATE = 1609,
        ERROR_EXTENDED_ERROR = 1208
    }
}
```